# Stein's Real Analysis theorem 1.4.3: Why it suffices to show the case $f=\chi_E$

Tags: real-analysis

In Stein's *Real Analysis*, theorem 1.4.3 states that:  Suppose $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then there exists a sequence of step functions $\{\psi_k\}$ that converges pointwise to $f(x)$ for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. (A step function is a function which can be written in the form $\Sigma_{i=1}^na_i\chi_{R_i}$, where the sum is finite and $R_i$s are rectangles.)

In the proof, the author only proved the case that $f(x)=\chi_E$ where $E$ a measurable set with $m(E)<+\infty$. **But I want to know why we can use this special situation to deduce the statement is true for any $f$ measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d$**. The author said that we need to use the previous theorem: Suppose $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d$
. Then there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{\psi_k\}$ that satisfies
$|\psi_k(x)|\leq |\psi_{k+1}(x)|$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\psi_k(x)=f(x)$ for any fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. (simple function is a function that can be written in the form $\Sigma_{i=1}^na_i\chi_{E_i}$, where the sum is finite and $E_i$ are measurable sets with finite measure.)

My attemot is that for any given $f$, we first choose $\{\psi_k\}$, a sequence of simple function, and for each $k$ we choose a sequence of step function $\{\varphi_{k,n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ that a.e approximate $\psi_k$, and then consider the sequence $\{\varphi_{k,N_k}\}$. However this may require uniformness because it change the sequence of limit. So how to rigorously show theorem 1.4.3 in the general case?

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry, this is a typo. I will fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Approximation of measurable function by step functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926976/approximation-of-measurable-function-by-step-functions)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you. But I think user stlinex's answer is more readable than the one in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are the details.

(1) There exist simple functions $\psi_k$, such that $\psi_k(x)\to f(x)$ for $x\in E_0^c$ with $m(E_0)=0$.

(2) For each simple funtion $\psi_k$, there exists a step function $\phi_k$ with $m(E_k)\leq 2^{-k}$, where $$E_k=\{x\mid \phi_k(x)\neq \psi_k(x)\}.$$

(3) Take $E=E_0\cup (\cap_{K=1}^\infty \cup_{j=K}^\infty E_j)$. We have $m(E)=0$ and
$$\lim \phi_k(x)=\lim \psi_k(x)=f(x), \quad x\in E^c.$$

Comment: 1) Please don't answer to duplicates. 2) I don't believe your (2).

Comment: @AnneBauval (2) follows from Stein's Real Analysis, p.21,  Theorem 1.3.4 (iv).  And I write down my understanding of the proof of Theorem 1.4.3 by Stein.

Comment: Thanks. @AnneBauval I will try to search more carefully next time before I ask a question. And I think this proof is correct.

Comment: To both: thank you and apologies, you are right.

Comment: Sorry for asking a different question. But in the same proof, it is claimed, after taking "slightly smaller" rectangles $R_j$, we have $m\left(E \Delta \cup_{j=1}^M R_j\right)\leq 2\epsilon$. May I ask why it is $2\epsilon$? Thanks.

Comment: I came up with something. Denote $F=\cup_{j=1}^M \tilde{R_j}$ and $F'=\cup_{j=1}^M R_j$. Then $F'\subset F$ is measurable. Also, $E\Delta F'= (E - F' ) \cup (F'-E)$, where $E-F'\subset (E-F) \cup (F-F')$ and $F'- E \subset F-E$. Then, as long as $m(F-F')\leq \epsilon$, we can have the result, following the proof of Theorem 3.4 on p.22. Correct?